# What happens if MASTER node is inaccessible by the clients in "Replicated levelDB Store" in ActiveMQ?

Tags: activemq-classic

So the documentation to the "[Replicated LevelDB Store](http://activemq.apache.org/replicated-leveldb-store.html)" says:

> The elected **master broker node starts and accepts client connections**. The other nodes go into slave mode and connect the the master and synchronize their persistent state /w it. **The slave nodes do not accept client connections**. All persistent operations are replicated to the connected slaves. If the master dies, the slaves with the latest update gets promoted to become the master. The failed node can then be brought back online and it will go into slave mode.

So one chosen master exist, it accepts client connections and the rest are replicated slave nodes who do not accept client connections. Fine.

So if the master dies it's all working fine - the master gets reelected, clients disconnect and they eventually connect to the new master. Awesome.

Now what happens if the master isn't dead from the perspective of Zookeeper, but it's just NOT ACCESSIBLE from clients. So a master is chosen, it's considered live(as i understand zookeeper's need to be able to connect to it to be considered available), but the actual clients can't connect to it?

Sure clients CAN connect to the other slave nodes, they just can't connect to the master. But the master won't ever be changed as it's live. Is that how it works?

Not sure i understood it right.

Answer (score 1):

LevelDB support in ActiveMQ is deprecated and has been for quite some time (years) so I'd suggest not bothering with it as there is no support and plenty of open bugs that will not be fixed.

I'd suggest taking a look instead at [ActiveMQ Artemis](http://activemq.apache.org/artemis/).

Answer (score 0):

You understand it right, and it's a reasonable design.

Clients only commuicate to master, and slaves are just used for backup. If what you described really happens, maybe caused by network problem, then you should fix the network(or any other possible reasons).